# REDUX-FORM error on handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am getting error while using **redux-form**

**Error msg in console**:

> - *bundle.js:32511 Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit()
>     an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop(…)*

the above error appeared on page load and button click

#### Please refer to the below code sample which cause the console error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { createPost } from '../actions/index';

class PostsNew extends Component {

  render() {
    const { fields: { title, categories, content }, handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.createPost)}>
        <h3>Create a new Post</h3>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...title}/>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Categories</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...categories}/>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Content</label>
          <textarea className="form-control" {...content}/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'PostsNewForm',
  fields: ['title', 'categories', 'content']
}, null, { createPost })(PostsNew);
```

---

> This was a step by step follow of **StephenGrider** redux tutorial

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how you invoked PostsNew component ?

Comment: PostsNew was invoked in Routes <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={PostsIndex} />
    <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew}/>
  </Route>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PostsNew` is Container (if this is directly invoked form Routes) then you have to make `handleSubmit` function instead of taking from `this.props`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { createPost } from '../actions/index';

class PostsNew extends Component {

  handleSubmit(formValues){
    console.log(formValues);
    //do what ever you want
  }

  render() {
    const { fields: { title, categories, content } } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit(this.props.createPost)}>
        <h3>Create a new Post</h3>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...title}/>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Categories</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...categories}/>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Content</label>
          <textarea className="form-control" {...content}/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**OR** 
In case `PostsNew` is React Component that is used inside a Container then you can pass `handleSubmit` in `props` of `PostsNew`

```
<PostsNew
 handleSubmit={ (values) => {console.log(values)}}
/>
```

Comment: Yes cool but when you are getting "handleSubmit" from props it does not work!

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal: this justs submit the form and reloads nothing happens.formvalues are undefined..

Comment: @dev_kishore: can you post the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass onsubmit props from parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { initialize } from 'redux-form';
import PostsNew from './PostsNew';


class App extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log('Submission received!', data);
    this.props.dispatch(initialize('contact', {})); // clear form
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <h1>App</h1>
        <PostsNew onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default connect()(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem until I explicitly imported connect into my file. After that, I was able to call this.props.createPost successfully.

This is my solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { createPost } from '../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class PostsNew extends Component {
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
             <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.createPost)}>
             <h3>Create a New Post</h3>
             <div className="form-group">
                 <label>Title</label>
                 <Field name="title" component="input" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
             </div>
             <div className="form-group">
                <label>Categories</label>
                <Field name="categories" component="input" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
             </div>
             <div className="form-group">
                <label>Content</label>
                <Field name="content" component="textarea" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
             </div>
             <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
         </form>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, {createPost})(reduxForm({
    form: 'PostsNew'
})(PostsNew));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. Check your action creator there should be a typo error in your action creator. Please refer the below action creator. If you followed the steps as he mentioned, this should work perfectly. What the error says is you don't have something called createPost in your props. Further more you can find my working project [here](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/blogpostsapp) in github.

```
export function createPost(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, props);
  return {
    type: CREATE_POST,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please install version **5** of **redux-form**.

`npm install --save redux-form@5`